# Java ArrayList<ArrayList<>> indexOf regardless of the order

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexof

I have created an ArrayList containing ArrayLists in Java.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Now I need to get the index of a similar list, using the `arrays.indexOf()` method. This works fine if the ArrayLists are in the same order, but I need it to work regardless of the order, or in other words I only want it to contain the same items.

How can I do this the easiest and fastest way? The array could possibly be very long, so I can't try every possible order.

Comment: what do you mean by `if the ArrayLists are in the same order`?

Comment: If order is unimportant, have you considered using a Set instead?

Comment: The items in the inner ArrayList must be in the same order as the ArrayList passed to the indexOf method, otherwise indexOf will return -1 (not found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in other words I only want it to contain the same items

This means that a `Set` is more appropriate than a `List`, since when you compare two `Set`s, you are checking if they contain the same items. There is no meaning to order.

```
ArrayList<Set<Integer>> arrays = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
```

Comment: Only if there can't be any duplicate in the collection. What the OP might really need is a bag.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a `Set` (if there are no duplicates), or sort the stored lists as well as the list you want to lookup. If the previous order is important, maintain a second list with the original data.